# How to set multiple annotations in iOS from Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, nsarray, mapkit, nsmutabledictionary

I have been trying to do this for a while now , but still not able to show multiple annotations.
Here is how i am storing data into `NSMutableDictionary` and then to `NSMutableArray` in `AppDelegate`

```
    // set the values to  mutable dictionary
    [_locationDictionary setObject:latitudeObj forKey:@"latitudeValue"];
    [_locationDictionary setObject:longitudeObj forKey:@"longitudeValue"];
    [_locationDictionary setObject:fromUser forKey:@"fromUser"];


    // add to array
    [_presenceArray addObject:_locationDictionary];
```

And this i am doing inside another ViewController.

```
   -(void)getPresenceData { 
   for(NSDictionary *dictObj in appDelegate.presenceArray) // this array that has dictionaries 
 {
      annotation = [[Annotation alloc]init];        // Annotation Class

     annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dictObj valueForKey:@"latitudeValue"]doubleValue], [[dictObj valueForKey:@"longitudeValue"]doubleValue]);

     annotation.title = [dictObj objectForKey:@"fromUser"];

     [self.buddyDataArray addObject:annotation];

     NSLog(@"buddy data array is %@", self.buddyDataArray);

     [self.mapView addAnnotations:buddyDataArray];
}
```

Comment: The addAnnotations (plural) method should be called _after_ the array is fully populated (after the loop).  Was buddyDataArray adding objects correctly or was it showing nil (because alloc+init was not done)?

Comment: yes array was adding objects...and i did alloc init inside viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this way... Make sure in your `presenceArray` dictionaries are getting stored.

```
-(void)getPresenceData { 
    for(NSDictionary *dictObj in appDelegate.presenceArray) // this array that has dictionaries 
    {
 annotation = [[Annotation alloc]init];        // Annotation Class
 annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[dictObj valueForKey:@"latitudeValue"]doubleValue], [[dictObj valueForKey:@"longitudeValue"]doubleValue]);
 annotation.title = [dictObj objectForKey:@"fromUser"];
 [self.mapview addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

As you are already looping than you dont need to create array of annotation objects.. You can add directly them to map as i did in above code..